# Getting last login by LIMIT 1 - PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

On my users account, I have a "last login" portion which displays the following:

```
<?php
     $getLog = "Select * from tblUserLogs where UserID = $id ORDER BY LogID DESC limit 1";
     $loadLog = mysql_query($getLog);
     while($Logs = mysql_fetch_array($loadLog)){
         $ID = $Logs['id'];
         $LastLogin = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($Logs['LastLog']));
         //$myLast = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $LastLogin);
         echo "<small>".$LastLogin."</small>";
    }
?>
```

However, it displays the current login date and time.

How should it be done? It should've been LIMIT 2 and display the smallest primary key. Is there a way to do it on the mysql statement?

Comment: what if you use `ORDER BY LastLog` in your query? else share the table structure to frame a better query.

Comment: the current login is your last login. What do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an offset, so you avoid the first entry.

```
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain enough - It will offset the data by the amount of the first number. So normally it takes that as 0, so it starts limiting the data from the first record returned. If you set the offset to 1, it will start from the 1st record, and then limit by 1, essentially giving you the second result.

Answer (score 0):

Either with a where (if you have a date column in your table)

```
SELECT * FROM tblUserLogs
WHERE UserId = <id>
AND loginDate <current login timestamp>
ORDER BY loginDate DESC
```

Or with a `LIMIT 1,1` (Skip One, Take One)

Comment: Should the <id> be $id?

Comment: This is no php code, just plain SQL with pseudo variables. You are right in your case you need `$id`. But, and I can't stress that enough: Use parameterized queries http://de2.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3574669/829533 and change the query

```
$getLog = "Select * from tblUserLogs where UserID = $id ORDER BY LogID DESC limit 1,1";
```